# SQL SELECT various names by various id's

Tags: php, mysql

I have this 3 tables:

main table:

```
  ID | OtherStuff1 | OtherStuff2 | IdProvince | IdTown 
-----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------
   1 |   Stuff1    |   Stuff2    |      1     |   1
```

province table:

```
ID | ProvinceName 
---+--------------
 1 |  ProvName1
```

town table:

```
ID |   TownName   
---+--------------
 1 |   TwName1
```

Obviously the main table has foreign relationships with the province table and the town table.

The result I want is this one:

```
ID | OtherStuff1 | OtherStuff2 | IdProvince |   IdTown   
---+-------------+-------------+------------+------------
 1 |   Stuff1    |   Stuff2    | ProvName1  |   TwName1
```

I want to show the main table but with the names instead of the ID's.

I looked up other questions and I tried this one:

```
    SELECT *
        FROM main AS a 
        INNER JOIN province AS b
        INNER JOIN town AS c
        WHERE a.IdProvince = b.ProvinceName
        AND a.IdTown = c.TownName 

    AND Id=1; # this is added by me because I want to filter by id on the
              # main table, I don't want all the rows, just one filtered by ID.
```

And this other one:

```
 SELECT *
       FROM main AS a, 
       INNER JOIN province AS b ON a.IdProvince = b.ProvinceName
       INNER JOIN town AS c ON a.IdTown = c.TownName
       WHERE Id=1;
```

Also I would like that the query could be easy to use in the way that If I have the same problem, but instead of the main table and 2 tables, I have main table and 4 tables I could also use it just adding more "INNER JOINS" for example?

I'm trying to do this but I couldn't get it right, I get this Sql wrong every time and I don't find the correct way to do this, any ideas?

I'm using PDO and I show this on a web page.

"AND Id=1" --> this will be used like this --> "AND Id=:filterID".

I hope I explained myself right!

If you have any doubts just ask, I'll answer as fast as I can!

Thanks in advance!

---------------------------------------------------------------EDIT--------------------------------------------------------------

I already tryed the 3 answers I got and it doesn't work, I don't know why, I will add images to back up so you see.

**This one works with no errors but I get no info back**

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, IdProvince, IdTown
 FROM main AS a 
 INNER JOIN province AS b 
 INNER JOIN town AS c 
   WHERE a.IdProvince = b.ProvinceName 
   AND a.IdTown = c.TownName 
AND a.Id=1
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvxjD.png)

**This one the same and no info back, but anyways I get extra columns from the other tables that I don't need there.**

```
SELECT * 
 FROM main AS a ,province AS b , town AS c 
  WHERE a.IdProvince = b.ProvinceName 
  AND a.IdTown = c.TownName 
AND a.Id=1
```

[This is the second result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4um8b.png)

**I also tryed this one but I can't get it to work always shows me an error**

```
SELECT *
   FROM 
      (main AS a 
      INNER JOIN province AS b ON a.IdProvince = b.ProvinceName) AS d
      INNER JOIN town AS c ON d.IdTown = c.TownName
   WHERE 
      Id=1
```

**I can't post more than 2 photos because I don't have enough reputation but I paste the error here:**

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'd
      INNER JOIN town AS c ON d.IdTown = c.TownName
   WHERE
      Id=1 LI' at line 4
```

*And in case you ask or doubt, I did put the info in the tables, 1 row each so there is something in, but for some reason it doesn't gives me back that info.*

-------------------------------------------------------LAST EDIT-------------------------------------------------------------

The 3 codes worked for me after trying them with a few edits, here are the 3 codes so people who might read this find this helpful.

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName
    FROM main AS a 
    INNER JOIN province AS b ON a.IdProvince = b.Id
    INNER JOIN town AS c ON a.IdTown = c.Id 
    WHERE a.Id=1;
```

---

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
    FROM main AS a 
    INNER JOIN (province AS b, town AS c) 
    ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id) 
    WHERE a.Id=1;
```

---

```
SELECT a.Id, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName 
    FROM main AS a ,province AS b , town AS c 
    WHERE a.IdProvince = b.Id
    AND a.IdTown = c.Id 
    AND a.Id=1;
```

Thanks a lot to the people who have helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just using a wrong SQL syntax on the second guess.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT *
   FROM 
      main AS a INNER JOIN (province AS b, town AS c)
      ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id)
      WHERE 
      a.Id=1;
```

The first guess is by the way old syntax and should not be used.

Edit: adapted to MariaDB Syntax

Comment: I already tryed your solution, didn't work :( look at the edit.

Comment: I did try again and gave me almost same error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'd
      INNER JOIN town AS c ON d.IdTown = c.Id
   WHERE
      a.Id=1 LIMIT ' at line 4

Comment: Seems like the MariaDB syntax is different; look at my edit

Comment: Now it works! But correcting a little mistake, I think you wanted to write:
SELECT *
   FROM main AS a
      INNER JOIN (province AS b, town AS c)
      ON (a.IdProvince = b.Id AND a.IdTown = c.Id)
      WHERE 
      a.Id=1

Comment: No problem! Thanks a lot!! I'll use your sintax now, since it's better than the old one and it looks clearer!

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are close, it's just that your join condition is wrong:

```
SELECT  main.ID, OtherStuff1, OtherStuff2, ProvinceName, TownName
    FROM main AS a 
    INNER JOIN province AS b ON a.IdProvince = b.Id
    INNER JOIN town AS c ON a.IdTown = c.Id 
    WHERE main.Id=1;
```

Comment: I was madly typing as you answer appeared.

Comment: I already tryed your solution, didn't work :( look at the edit.

Comment: Your edit does not include my query, it includes 3 new queries where none of them matches my answer. Please edit your question once again to include the relevant tables DDL statements, some sample data as DML statements and desired results.

Comment: The first query is yours, I had to edit it because It gave me this error ---> #1054 - Unknown column 'main.Id' in 'field list' 

So I changed "main.Id" for "a.Id" and I don't know why the clause WHERE is changed maybe I did not copy paste well, just chaging "main.Id" for "a.Id" works for me just as I intended, thanks very much!

Comment: No, it's not. You are comparing idProvince with ProvinceName. Anyway I found a mistake in my query, so I've edited my answer. Still it would be best if you could provide the relevant tables DDL + DML for sample data, so that we could test our answers.

Answer (score 0):

this is work for me ,

Please feild name first ,if its not proper then first fix it then execute ,

```
SELECT * 
FROM main AS a ,province AS b , town AS c 
WHERE a.IdProvince = b.id
AND a.IdTown = c.id 
AND a.Id=1;
```

Comment: While implicit joins still works in most (if not all) databases, explicit joins have been  a part of ANSI SQL for more then 25 years now. There really is no need to use implicit joins anymore, ever.

Comment: Yes , Zohar from now you can use this type structure . :)

Comment: I didn't say you can't use it, I said it's better to use explicit joins. Read Aaron bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) for details.

Comment: Ohh Yeah!
But it's easy to use so i use this method and not complex for understanding.

Comment: I already tryed your solution, didn't work :( look at the edit.

Comment: Sorry , Bro Please check i edit my solution for you i hope this is work for you